# I Configure httpd.conf on macos to allow SymLinks with Options FollowSymLinks but I still get 403 you have no permission

Tags: macos, apache, symlink

My local apache setting on MacOS 10.12.5 uses the default setting /private/etc/apache2/http.conf

This includes following settings for directory:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
   Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
```

According to the above, I should be able to open webpages which are contained in subfolders of /Documents/ when these subfolders are symbolic links from another place in my computer.  I have made sure that these folders and files are read/write/executable by all both on the original directory and on the symlinked position under /Documents/.  But I still get the error:

```
    Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /aliastest/index.html
on this server.
```

This is the relevant info from ls -l ./Documents/

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel       44 Sep 21 18:02 aliastest -> /Users/iani/Documents/001DEV/SITES/aliastest
```

and:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 iani  staff  230 Sep 21 18:01 index.html
```

I have also checked the includes in the httpd.conf file and do not find any conflict or override there. I restarted apachectl.  Problem persists.

Any hints as to how to enable browsing of pages symlinked folders in my root web directory on macos?

Thanks

Iannis Zannos